# Java: String to Date

Tags: java, date

I have spent lot of time to convert my string to date. I have string in

```
Fri Jan 04 12:32:28 CST 2013
```

format. And my code is below

```
myDate=(Date) new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(str);
```

Please help me how to get rid of this. This code throws exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

Comment: get rid of what? Do you get any exception? Unexpected output?

Comment: This code throws exception

Comment: Check your import statement. It should import `java.util.Date`, and not `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. In the future questions, include them immediately if you can't decipher them. Exceptions tell namely about the cause of the problem and inherently thus also about the solution. You should not ignore them as if they are decoration.

Answer (score 2):

Use the import statement

```
import java.util.Date;
```

instead of

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

And yes... please do not ignore exceptions. Moreover, while using auto import make sure what class you need. In the Java API there are many classes which might have similar names. But what matters is the fully qualified name.

So make sure that you have the right fully qualified name in the import statements.

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleDateFormat#parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse) returns `java.util.Date` not the `java.sql.Date`.
But you have imported `java.sql.Date` ,means you are trying to convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`.So you are getting `ClassCastException`.
 So your import statment should be (as  @Rohit Jain comment)

```
     import java.util.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("put your format string here");
DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(str);
```

For format strings check out [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)